TimeSequencer in message_filters not compiling
I'm trying to use ROS 2 Jazzy message_filters::TimeSequencer with a message_filters::Subscriber to periodically receive messages. However my code does not compile and I get the following error :
subscriber_member_function.cpp(24,89): error C2664: 'message_filters::TimeSequencer<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure>::TimeSequencer(rclcpp::Duration,rclcpp::Duration,uint32_t,rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr)': impossible to convert argument 4 from 'message_filters::Subscriber<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure,rclcpp::Node>' to 'rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr'
subscriber_member_function.cpp(24,127): message : No user-defined conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
message_filters/time_sequencer.h(111,3): message : see the declaration of 'message_filters::TimeSequencer<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure>::TimeSequencer' 

I know that the expected last argument is of type rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr, but I'm not familiar with ROS. I searched online and couldn't find any working example for this version of ROS. I tried replacing it with nh, and although it compiles, the topic_callback is never called.
Below is my code.
subscriber_member_function.cpp
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "tutorial_interfaces/msg/measure.hpp" 
#include "message_filters/subscriber.h"
#include "message_filters/time_sequencer.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static auto logger = rclcpp::get_logger("logger");

void topic_callback(const tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure::ConstSharedPtr& msg)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(logger, "Received: Time: %u sec, %u nsec, Value: '%lf'", msg->stamp.sec, msg->stamp.nanosec, msg->value);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr nh = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("minimal_subscriber");
  message_filters::Subscriber<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure> sub(nh, "accel_x");
  message_filters::TimeSequencer<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure> seq(rclcpp::Duration(10ms), rclcpp::Duration(2000ms), 20, sub);
  seq.registerCallback(std::bind(&topic_callback, std::placeholders::_1));
  rclcpp::spin(nh);
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

publisher_member_function.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "tutorial_interfaces/msg/measure.hpp" 

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalPublisher()
  : Node("minimal_publisher"), count_(0)
  {
    publisher_ = this->create_publisher<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure>("accel_x", 10);
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
      500ms, std::bind(&MinimalPublisher::timer_callback, this));
  }

private:
  void timer_callback()
  {
    auto message = tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure();

    message.stamp.sec = 1600000000;
    message.stamp.nanosec = count_;
    message.value = 1.00001 + count_++;
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: Time: %u sec, %u nsec, Value: '%lf'", message.stamp.sec, message.stamp.nanosec, message.value);
    publisher_->publish(message);
  }
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  rclcpp::Publisher<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure>::SharedPtr publisher_;
  size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalPublisher>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

Measure.msg
builtin_interfaces/Time stamp
float64 value


The solution was to call both the subscriber and the node handler, like this :
message_filters::TimeSequencer<tutorial_interfaces::msg::Measure> seq(sub, rclcpp::Duration(10ms), rclcpp::Duration(2000ms), 20, nh);

